# Indexing an int? How does this work?

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10,20,30};
    cout << -2[arr];
    return 0;
}
```

prints `-30`. How? Why?

Comment: `cout<<-2[arr];` I would never let that go through in a code review... way to be confusing for no reason.

Comment: I humbly disagree with the dupe. This question involves a significant amount of difference, in terms with the operator precedence involved in it and misconception of UB, as shown in (now deleted) comments. I request a re-consideration for this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case,

```
 cout<<-2[arr];
```

gets translated as

```
cout<<-(arr[2]);
```

because,

1. [array indexing boils down to pointer arithmatic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/3137699), so, the position of array name and the index value can be interchanged in notation.

   <sup>The linked answer is in C, but valid for C++ also.</sup>
2. regarding the explicit `()`s, you can check about the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) here.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this statement

```
cout << -2[arr];
```

First, know that even though it looks strange [the following is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

```
2[arr] == arr[2]
```

That being said `operator[]` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `-`. So you are actually trying to invoke

```
-(arr[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, `2[arr]` is actually the same thing as `arr[2]`.

Due to operator precedence, `-2[arr]` as parsed as `-(2[arr])`. This means that the entire expression evaluates to negating the 3rd element of `arr`, i.e. `-30`.